# Choosing squares from a grid of $n\times n$ squares.

Tags: combinatorics

Out of the $25$
squares in a $5\times5$ grid in how many ways $3$ squares can be
selected such that no two of them are on the
same row or column or **diagonal** ?

Hi

Though a similar question is already answered for row and column constraint I was interested in knowing how one would approach it if one adds another constraint (that of a diagonal).

I think I know the approach.

Could you please validate it and let me know how to formulate an equation and proceed further? 
[image]

[5*5 Square](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEznQ.jpg)

For choosing the first square :

1. Considering the squares along the perimeter of the grid if you select any square ( for example the lower bottom ) then you would be left with $12$ possible squares to choose from.
2. If you first choose any square along the perimeter of the inner $3\times3$  square, you would have $10$ squares to choose from .
3. If you select the innermost square first, then you have $8$ squares to choose from.

How to proceed beyond this?

Comment: This is the number of ways to place $3$ non-attacking queens on a $5\times5$ chessboard.  I doubt there is any way to do it other than explicitly enumerating the solutions. Google "n queens problem" for more information.

Comment: Without the diagonal constraint, the number of choices for the second square is independent of where you choose the first square (and also for the third square, given the first two). With the diagonal constraint, the positions of these squares matter, so the same kind of reasoning doesn't apply. As @saulspatz mentions, you will have to count them by brute force (exploiting symmetry may help a little though).